# Translate Quadratic so that $x^4-x^2 = 0$

Tags: graphing-functions, quadratics

I need to math for a button bounce with jquery, and the simplest and cleanest way to do that is figure out the equation from 0 to 1.

The equation is in the form of $x^4 - x^2 + 0$ and needs to equal  $1$  at $x=0$

Such that the equation

$ -\dfrac{(x^4)}{32 }+ \dfrac{(20x^2)}{32}$

is `1` at `x=0`, and decreases to `0` at `x=1`

Normally the equation is equal to `0` when `x=5`.  I just need to translate it along the x-axis so that it's `0` at `x=1`

Comment: What exactly is the equation you want to translate?

Comment: Are you sure you copied the formulas correctly? The polynomial $-(x^4)/32 + (20x^2)/32$ has roots at $0$ and $\pm 2\sqrt5,$ not at $5.$ Also, please don't use the word "equation" to describe something that has no "$=$" sign (the word "formula" may be what you need), and please proofread; is "I need to math for a button bounce" something one might write in the English language?

Answer (score 0):

For *any* function $f(x)$, we can define the "translated right by $k$" version of it as:
$$\text{translate}_k(x) = f(x-k)$$
We can see this is the right definition by trying out some values:
\begin{align*}
\text{translate}_k(0) & = f(-k) \\
\text{translate}_k(k) & = f(0) \\
\text{translate}_k(k+1) &= f(1)
\end{align*}
It sounds like you have some $f(x)$ such that $f(5) = 0$, and you want to translate this so that $f(1) = 0$ (so left by 4).
Then, we'd want to use:
$$\text{translate}_{-4}(x) = f(x+4)$$
This gives the equation:
$$-\frac{(x+4)^4}{32}+\frac{20}{32}(x+4)^2$$

Comment: How does that verify $f(0)=1,f(1)=0$ ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a horizontal shift to do the transformation for you. Change $x$ to $x+4$ and you are done. For example if you have $(x-5)^2=0$, change it to $(x+4-5)^=0$ which simplifies to $(x-1)^2=0.$